# Images being duplicated in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer 9 is rendering [my webpage](http://element17.com/) incorrectly, and I'm not sure why.  It's duplicating each thumbnail, with one showing the fade-in effect, and the other the magnifying-glass image.  Correct functionality can be seen in Chrome and Firefox (versions 21.0.1180.49 and 14.0.1 respectively).  Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?  CSS is [here](http://element17.com/css/main.css).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind validating the page first?
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Felement17.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: It looks like you can't have an <a> inside another <a>, is that correct?  If so, I'm not sure how to fix that, as that's kind of the behaviour I'm looking for...

Comment: No you can't have an <a> inside another. The way you are trying to achieve it is probably semantically incorrect, go about it a different way (have the <a> after it, code wise, but then just position it on top of it)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much.  I have done this differently, and now everything is working great (but for transitions in IE9, but oh well).  Thank you!